# Jet Airways cancellation

Tags: jet-airways

I booked direct with Jet Airways: Dublin-Amsterdam-Bengaluru-Paris-Dublin. They notified me of cancellation of the Jet Airways Amsterdam to Bengaluru flight and said I could seek a partial refund for that. The other legs of the journey are operated by other airlines Aer Lingus and Air France and are not cancelled.

There is no alternative flight from Amsterdam to Bengaluru.

Can I cancel the full itinerary and get a full refund? Or claim it on insurance or VISA card?

Answer (score 5):

Jet Airways went bankrupt. Your chances of getting a refund are slim and none.

Your best bet would be hope your credit card company refunds the ticket fare to you.

[What happens to plane tickets in case of airline bankruptcy?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73075/what-happens-to-plane-tickets-in-case-of-airline-bankruptcy)